# Download chunks of MP4 file from iOS

Tags: objective-c, http-headers, mp4

I am developing an iOS app that synchronises with GoPro cameras.
One of the feature requires downloading MP4 from the GoPro (potentially huge).

I basically have a url like: http://10.9.9.5/whatever/video.mp4.

However, I only need parts of the video, let's say between 1:00 and 1:05. 
I am thinking on downloading just parts of the MP4, using HTTP "Range" header. I believe that it's possible and I will get a bunch of bytes.

However, is it a valid file? Will I be able to create a MP4 ? Do I need the MP4 header with meta information? Do any of you faced this kind of challenge?

I am using Objective C but I believe that this is a general question.

Answer (score 1):

The MP4 file is a container for video that is structured around something called `boxes`. Probably you'll have `h.264` video in that MP4 file, knowing that, you'll need to know the structure of the file you are trying to chunk.

Depending on the way it is encoded you'll have to look for a box with metadata that'll allow you to search for the correct part of the file either at the beginning or at the end, but you'll have to reconstruct a valid MP4 with the data you get from the original file.

You can see a reference of the file format here http://xhelmboyx.tripod.com/formats/mp4-layout.txt.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, very useful. Any idea about how can I read the structure of the file?

Comment: You have a reference of the different box types on the link I provided in the answer, you can see a higher level explanation here: http://mpeg.chiariglione.org/standards/mpeg-4/iso-base-media-file-format